# How to write inline YAML (flow style) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, yaml, pretty-print, aeson

I'm using [`Data.Yaml`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.8.15.2/docs/Data-Yaml.html) to store some data in human readable format. However, some parts of the data are lists or matrices of numbers. The YAML output, [block sequence style](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2543032), is quite verbose:

```
- - 1
  - 2
  - 3
- - 4
  - 5
```

Instead I'd like these parts to be encoded in [flow sequence style](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2542413), just like

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5]]
```

Is there a way how to do that?

Comment: you want your generated YAML to contain haskell lists?

Comment: @rampion: Possibly _flow sequence style_ lists, instead of the current _block sequence style_ ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately not. `yaml` uses `libyaml`. While you would like to use the [flow sequence style](https://github.com/snoyberg/yaml/blob/a440479185e0a689576a2c1f621ff11ff088e3cd/libyaml/emitter.c#L728-L771), the [current implementation](https://github.com/snoyberg/yaml/blob/a440479185e0a689576a2c1f621ff11ff088e3cd/libyaml/emitter.c#L1041-L1059) uses `YAML_ANY_SEQUENCE_STYLE` (0) instead of `YAML_FLOW_SEQUENCE_STYLE` (2), and therefore `YAML_BLOCK_SEQUENCE_STYLE` (1, but the emitter only checks for equality with `YAML_FLOW_SEQUENCE_STYLE`).

This is hardcoded into the [`toEventRaw`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.8.15.2/docs/src/Text-Libyaml.html#toEventRaw) wrapper in Haskell. It should be possible to write `encodeWith`, that uses a special `toEventRawWith` and takes additional options, but that's currently not the case. <del>You could [open a feature request](https://github.com/snoyberg/yaml/issues/new),</del> There's a [feature request](https://github.com/snoyberg/yaml/issues/77), however.

**Edit:** Indeed, `Data.Yaml.encode` will return `"[[1,2,3], [4,5]]"` if one substitutes all occurrences of `0 -- YAML_ANY_SEQUENCE_STYLE` with `2 -- YAML_FLOW_SEQUENCE_STYLE` in `Text/Libyaml.hs`. So you either need to patch the library locally, or ask that feature request.